# Proof of an irrationality criterion

Tags: irrational-numbers

I have attached a proposition whose proof I don't understand at two points. Here are my questions:

1. Why do we have $|a_{0n}+\theta_{1}a_{1n}+\dots+\theta_{k}a_{kn}|<(\rho-\varepsilon)^{-n}$ for sufficiently large $n$?
2. Why do we have $[1,...,n]<e^{(1+\varepsilon)n}$ by the prime number theorem?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This follows immediately from the [characterization of the radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) of an arbitrary power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ as $\rho^{-1} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} |b_n|^{1/n}$.

2) One of the equivalent formulations of the Prime Number Theorem is that the [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\psi(x)$ is asymptotic to $x$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty} \psi(x)/x = 1$.  If you read the definition of $\psi(x)$ carefully, you will find that $\exp(\psi(n))$ is exactly equal to the LCM $[1,2,\ldots,n]$, by considering how many times the term $\log p$ appears in $\psi(n)$ for each prime $p$.  It then follows immediately that $[1,2,\ldots,n] \le \exp((1+\epsilon)n)$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @R.A. Write out the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$ and apply it to the function $\psi(x)/x$.